# How to insert a hyperlink and table into a cell in the Excel sheet?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, outlook

This is the code in outlook VBA

```
Sub Sendmail()
    Dim olItem As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim xlBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlSht As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim sPath As String
    Dim iRow As Long
    Dim strRFIitems As String
    Dim Signature As String

    sPath = "**"

    '   // Excel
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    '   // Workbook
    Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(sPath)
    '   // Sheet
    Set xlSht = xlBook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    '   // Create e-mail Item
    Set olItem = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    strRFIitems = xlSht.Range("E2")
    Signature = xlSht.Range("F2")

    With olItem
        .To = Join(xlApp.Transpose(xlSht.Range("A2", xlSht.Range("A9999").End(xlUp))), ";")
        .CC = Join(xlApp.Transpose(xlSht.Range("B2", xlSht.Range("B9999").End(xlUp))), ";")
        .Subject = xlSht.Range("C2")
        .Body = xlSht.Range("D2") & Signature
        .Attachments.Add (strRFIitems)
        .Display
    End With

    '   // Close
    xlBook.Close SaveChanges:=True
    '   // Quit
    xlApp.Quit

    Set xlApp = Nothing
    Set xlBook = Nothing
    Set xlSht = Nothing
    Set olItem = Nothing
End Sub
```

The code retrieves the data from the linked Excel sheet. Now the
problem is with `.Body = xlSht.Range("D2") & Signature` this line
of code, where the body of the mail is retrieved from the D2 cell of
Excel sheet.

And as per my requirement, the body of the mail should contain a hyper
link and table along with the text.

Example:

> Hello All,
>   Please update the details in the portal
>   portal link :http://google.com.
>
> Please contact me for any clarifications.
>
> Below mentioned details needs to be updated:
>       table has to be inserted here

Suppose above mentioned text is inserted into a cell of Excel.

1. List item
   This `portal link: http://google.com.` becomes a plain text not a hyper link.
   If I try to make it a hyper link the entire cell becomes hyper link. i.e even the text.
2. List item
   How to insert table into a cell of Excel sheet and call it using Outlook VBA

**Query:**
How to insert a hyperlink and table along with the test
message into a cell of Excel and retrieve it as it is using the above
mentioned code and send a mail containing hyperlink and table.

Comment: A cell can be a hyperlink as a formula which is the entire cell or a hyperlink object which is the entire cell but you cannot have a hyperlink as part of other text (e.g. hyperlink within a sentence or paragraph) in a single cell.

Comment: Usually the email apps like Outlook automatically turn text URLs into links if the email is received. Did you try that?

Comment: can you share your spreadsheet?

Answer (score 0):

For hyperlink you can use the following code:

```
Range("K6").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "test"
Range("K6").Select
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:= _
    "http://www.google.com", TextToDisplay:="test"
Range("K6").Select
Selection.Hyperlinks(1).Follow NewWindow:=False, AddHistory:=True
```

Comment: I believe the OP wants to create a hyperlink as an isolated part of a larger text within a single cell.

Comment: @Harsh Sharma, thanks for the code. But as Jeepad rightly mentioned I want to this hyper link along with the text message and a table in the same cell.

Comment: @Jeeped could you please share the screenshot of what exactly you want?

Comment: Hey, sorry Jeeped that was for @Sai

Comment: @HarshSharma And I **hardly** recommend you to read [VBA Best Practices: Avoid using select or activate](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices/9292/avoid-using-select-or-activate) unless your code should be an example of bad practice!

Comment: @ Harsh, the sample is here:http://www.ekobit.com/UploadedFiles/image/image_20.png and https://www.ablebits.com/_img/outlook-templates-phrases/reply-with-template-outlook2013.png